питон spacy при установке ошибка декодинга
При установке spacy через:
pip install spacy
Выдает ошибку:
File "C:\Users\MrTimotey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xeb' in position 2810: character maps to 
[end of output]
      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis

Просьба помочь. Сам еще только разбираюсь в питоне, много чего не понимаю)

дубликаты где-то здесь

Да что ж всем питон 3.13 то нужен прям. Вы убедитесь сначала, что библиотеки, которые вы планируете использовать, под него уже переделаны. )
